# Azure Cloud Shell editor is not opening

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

Trying to create and edit `.yaml` file in Azure Cloud Shell (Kubernetes manifest file for testing ingress in AKS). But neither `code demo.yaml` (or `code .`), nor clicking on `{ }` is opening editor.

[image]

**I tried**:

- Unmounting fileshare (`clouddrive unmount`) and re-initialized cloudshell (PowerShell)
- Used multiple Azure accounts (to check whether the problem is related to any particular account)

**Error in chrome dev tool console**

[image]

Comment: We have tested in our subscription & we are able to open the cloud shell editor using the cmdlets `code <filename>`  or  ``code .``  or using `{}` in the cloud shell menu as shown in this gif  https://i.imgur.com/wvrHVpl.gifv

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT I tried with my personal subscription and a different subscription in my client environment. So, my conclusion is "it is not related to subscription". I did not find the reason yet, still investigating...

Comment: Tried with : Edge and Chrome